# Jquery plugin available to display blocks when each one are expanded on event of clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please provide help to choose a plugin which

1) should display 3 blocks of `div`(width=32%) in a line at first

2)when we click on view more of a particular `div`, that `div` should expand(width-64%) still, the other `div` blocks(width=32%) should find space which will fit them and automatically go and sit in the space available(not random spacing, `div` movement should be horizontal).

3)This should work when we click on the div which is expanded to 64% to expand it further to 96% and other `div` should fit in properly without any unwanted gap.

Did try doing it using CSS and simple JQuery(click event), but it didn't work.

Please refer to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tAyDn/)

Comment: r u searching for accordian http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Could you show here the way you tried with CSS and JQuery?

Comment: just googled it : http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/ . If you really want something so custom, you'll probably have to create it by yourself.

Comment: no its not accordian, [http://impulsestudios.ca/images/portfolio/racer-x-brand_products.jpg](example), if we click on 1st product, its width will increase, but the other products will occupy the space that is available without getting distorted

Comment: With description u have given i could only figure out accordian...anyway just fiddle i made before ur comment thought it will help...http://jsbin.com/AgETULAs/3/edit

Comment: If u are not looking for accordian.you can create fluid responsive divs using uikit and jquery. http://www.getuikit.com/

Comment: responsive is not the issue, div placement in space available, for this i need help